# How do I get arctan MATH function in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

How do I get arctan MATH function in iphone SDK?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `atan(double)`

Comment: How can i use arccos MATH function ??

Comment: @Devang: `acos()` unsurprisingly.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/acos.3.html

Comment: This man page might be of help http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/math.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/math

Comment: Does it return the value in radians or degrees?

Comment: Its in radians (*180/π) for degrees

Answer (score 4):

Use the "2nd"-function under the "("-key, top left with the iphone in horizontal position. The tan key will change to tan-1, i.e. arctan.