# How do I find cos−1(−0.6481) {cos inverse} of MATH function in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get arctan MATH function in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339595/how-do-i-get-arctan-math-function-in-iphone-sdk)

How do I find cos−1(−0.6481)  {cos inverse} of MATH function in Objective-C?

Comment: This was answered in the comments to the answer on your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339595/how-do-i-get-arctan-math-function-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: Few notes that may help you in getting better answers in SO. 1)Please read the comments too, not only answers. 2)If you have same problem of your previous question, instead of asking a new question discuss in that question. Do not ask again what is already answered. 3)Accept the answer which solves your problem. (I answered this question before seeing the comment. If I knew that the math.h is already referred in your previous question, I would not bother to answer this. Other members of SO may feel the same.)

Comment: @taskinoor :  as i'm new here. so i was not knowing that........sorry for tht.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`math.h` is available in iPhone.

```
#import <math.h>

double v = acos(−0.6481);
```